# Can't run Cuke4Nuke

Tags: cucumber

I have installed, confirmed installation and followed the steps mentioned in the links below:

http://gojko.net/2010/01/01/bdd-in-net-with-cucumber-cuke4nuke-and-teamcity/

http://cuke4ninja.com/sec_hello_world_net.html

Once I try to run `Cuke4Nuke bin\debug\Cuke4NukeExample.dll`
I get an error message.

I tried to run Cuke4Nuke alone with no parameters and I see the same error message as with the `bin\debug\Cuke4NukeExample.dll`

**Here is the error message:**

> E:\Visual Projects>cuke4nuke
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:249
>   :in `attach_function': Function '_get_errno' not found in [msvcrt.dll]
>   (FFI::Not FoundError)
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
>   rocess/functions.rb:12:in`attach_pfunc'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
>   rocess/functions.rb:64:in `<module:Functions>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
>   rocess/functions.rb:8:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i n
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i n`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-process-0.7.0/lib/win32/p
>   rocess.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i n`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i n
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cuke4nuke-0.4.0/lib/cuke4nuke/m
>   ain.rb:4:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i n
>   `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:i n`
>   require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cuke4nuke-0.4.0/bin/cuke4nuke:4
>   :in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/bin/cuke4nuke:23:in`load'
>           from C:/Ruby193/bin/cuke4nuke:23:in `'

Thanks

Comment: Deleted answer.  Replaced with this comment: From the cuke4nuke wiki: "Cuke4Nuke is no longer under active development. Check out [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) for a current .NET version of Cucumber."